# Evaluating number of collisions between particles in a closed container

Tags: algebra-precalculus

This question is regarding whether the following method of calculating number of collisions in a closed container is correct or not.

So, it goes as follows:-

First of all we make a table about the number of collisions a constant number of particles can have in a closed container at a given time (also have included the figures which help us to evaluate the data in the table).
[image: Table]

[image: Figure]

We can conclude that the particles can collide with the walls and also among themselves. In the later part, we can say that the particles are arranged in a polygon (not necessarily regular). Hence the collision can be along the sides and the diagonals.

Taking Total No. of Collisions as $c$ and number of particles as $n$, we can define the relation:
$c = n + n + [n(n-3)/2]$ ;

where, the $1$st $n$ quantifies the collision with the walls, the $2$nd $n$ quantifies the collisions along the sides and $n(n-3)/2$ quantifies the collision along the diagonals.

We have almost reached the end. One change in the Equation is required.

We must create a constraint which allows the following phenomenon:

When we reach a higher number of particles, the space in the container will fill. Hence some particles will be such that they do not collide at all.

Hence we introduce the constraint, as follows:

$c = (a-n)(2n + [n(n-3)/2])$  (the table above doesn't include this constraint)

Graphing the equation also gives a valid graph.
[image: Graph]

The graph perfectly shows that the no. of collisions increase first, then reach a maxima which is close around to 50-70% and then goes decreasing as more and more particles accumulate and less space is left for the particles to even perform a collision.

So, coming back to the original question, is this whole method correct ?

Please anyone tell......

Comment: I'm confused as to what you are counting. The number of collisions per second, per hour, in eternity? Also you are treating a particles collision with a wall as equivalent to a collision with another particle, as if that is equally probable. Furthermore, I would expect the number of collisions to rise continually with more particles, unless you are trying to model a state transition into a solid. And what about temperature?

Comment: Sorry for saying it a particle, I mean a body like a ball. But with small dimensions like in milimetres. It has definite size and volume. Not a particle as in Kinetic Theory Of Gases. Temperature has no effect. And this methodology calculates number of probable collisions which can happen at a given time.